# Fileprovider does not get loaded when application is run from /Applications folder

Tags: macos, sandbox, fileprovider

I have developed a functional Application that uses the new NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension.
Everything worked as expected until I started deployment and realized, that my application cannot add domain successfully while being run from */Applications* folder.
Calling:

```
[NSFileProviderManager addDomain:fileProviderDomain completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error){}];
```

This call results in error:

```
Error Domain=NSFileProviderErrorDomain Code=-2001 "The application cannot be used right now." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The application cannot be used right now.}
```

Running the application from XCode build dir or *˜/Desktop* fileprovider extension works as expected.

Upon closer inspection in console around a moment of calling "addDomain", I can see a line that does not come up when running the application from a different location.

```
kernel Sandbox: fileproviderd(448) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/TestFileProvider.app
```

I have tried changing about everything in codesign and sandbox in build settings but no change.
I have also tried making app in Obj-C and swift too - makes no difference.
Any suggestions?

---

For reference here is my question on apple developer forums:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696254

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution? I'm also facing this exact issue when I create a distribution package.

Comment: @HarshitGindra I have followed the solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71043758/1264720
Also, main app needs a provisioning profile

Comment: Thanks @Marcel Vyberal, adding the correct provisioning profile fixed the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I've succeeded to load the FileProvider plugin under /Applications folder:

1. The application should be installed to /Applications folder as root user.
2. The entitlements file (of main app) should contain the "com.apple.application-identifier" item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue when trying to package a FileProvider Extension into my MacOS electron application.

The key to the solution for me was as stated in @HarshitGindra's comment: I needed to add the correct provisioning profile. Turns out the automatically generated provisioning profile from XCode was using my personal developer ID as opposed to my organization ID and so notarization failed.

I determined it was a notarization issue by running the following command:

`spctl -vvv --assess --type exec <path-to-app>`

I recieved the error:
`source=Unnotarized Developer ID`

Here are all the steps I took to resolve this issue:

1. Add an "App Group" capability to my FileProvider Extension
2. Add the App Group ID in the following format: group..
3. Do the equivalent in electron (add App Group entitlement to entitlements file)
4. Turn off automatic signing under your extension target in XCode
5. Download the provisioning profile for your extension from your Apple Developer Account (you may need to create one) and set XCode to use that profile under signing

Hope this helps!